# Ordenar registros por consulta con UNION MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Mi problema es el siguiente.Tengo una consulta que tiene un UNION.Necesito que el resultado final de la query muestre primeramente los registros de la 1ra query ordenados por su nombre y luego los registros de la 2da query ordenados por su nombre de igual manera.Ejemplo:
Tabla original

```
id   nombre estado
1   Jesus   1
2   Carlos  null
3   Alberto 1
4   Pedro   0
5   Alicia  0
6   celeste 0



Resultado esperado:
Alberto
Carlos
Jesus
Alicia
celeste
Pedro

Resultado obtenido:
Jesus
Carlos
Alberto
Pedro
Alicia
celeste
La query que tengo es algo como esto pero no obtengo el resultado esperado
```

```
(SELECT nombre FROM Usuario WHERE estado=1 OR estado is NULL ORDER BY nombre ASC)

UNION 

(SELECT nombre FROM Usuario WHERE estado=0 ORDER BY nombre ASC)
```

Comment: Cual es el resultado que muestra tu query... vuelvo a preguntar?

Comment: Agrupa bien mostrando primero los registros de la 1ra query y luego los de la segunda pero no agarra el order by.Por defecto ordena por el id de la tabla.

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir... Mostranos como salen los datos. si no, estamos trabajando en el aire por algo que deberia andar bien.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta con los datos reales de la tabla lo que obtengo y lo que espero.No agarra el order by por el nombre..está ordenando por el id

Comment: Te animas a hacer un fiddle con esto? tengo miedo que sea un problema de mysql o de tu instalacion

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f83b4/7
Aca está ya con la respuesta que me dieron abajo funcionando,gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

necesitas entonces una columna adicional para ordenar (No sé si esta columna en tu caso es estado, pero puede funcionar), haciendo un subquery como el siguiente:

```
    SELECT nombre, ord1 FROM (
    (SELECT nombre, 1 as ord1 FROM Usuario WHERE estado=1 OR estado IS NULL)

    UNION 

    (SELECT nombre, 2 as ord1 FROM Usuario WHERE estado=0)) as subq
    ORDER BY ord1, nombre;
```

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con los datos reales de la tabla, lo que obtengo y lo que espero.No agarra el order by por el nombre..está ordenando por el id.La consulta me da un error en mysql

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY estado, nombre' at line 7.
En la pregunta original puse todo detallado como deberia quedar

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta, añadí un alias en el subquery, que es el problema que creo puedes estar teniendo.

Comment: Ahora muestra este orden:Alicia celeste Pedro Alberto y Jesus.Carlos que es el que esta con estado NULL no lo muestra.Deberia quedar: Alberto Carlos Jesus Alicia celeste Pedro.

Comment: Hola, modifiqué de nuevo mi respuesta para incluir una nueva condición, en la primera parte del query se toma ahora cualquiera que tenga estado = 1 o NULL

Comment: Carlos Alicia celeste Pedro Alberto Jesus :(

Comment: Lo modifiqué de nuevo, espero que ahora si funcione ;)

Comment: Ahora si amigo!!!Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y agregando lo que dice la documentacion de mysql: Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.  o sea, el order interno no sirve absolutamente para nada

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas `UNION` para esto, puedes resolverlo así:

```
SELECT 
    nombre 
FROM Usuario 
WHERE estado=1 OR estado=0 
ORDER BY estado DESC, nombre ASC;
```

Con `UNION`  la consulta podría ser así:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM ( 
         SELECT 1 AS m_order, Nombre 
         FROM Usuario WHERE estado=1 OR estado IS NULL 
         ORDER BY nombre 
       ) a
UNION  
SELECT b.*
  FROM ( 
         SELECT 2 AS m_order, Nombre 
         FROM Usuario WHERE estado=0 
         ORDER BY Nombre
       ) b 
ORDER BY m_order, Nombre
```

No queda claro qué orden quieres para la primera sub-consulta, si ordenados por estado `NULL` primero o no. En ese caso sólo cambias `estado DESC` por `estado ASC`.

Comment: El tema es que los registros de la 1ra query el estado puede ser o 1 o NULL(pertenecen al mismo grupo),la segunda solo con 0.Y deberia ponerme primero los registros en 1 o NULL ordenados alfabeticamente y luego los registros en 0 ordenados alfabeticamente.Ahi corregi la pregunta

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans no queda claro lo que quieres. Si quieres también los nulos sólo lo agregas como otro `OR` en el  `WHERE`. Si pones en la pregunta un pequeño extracto de tu set de datos y de los resultados que esperas quizá se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: Si quieres los nulos, el criterio quedaría así: `WHERE estado=1 OR estado=0 OR IS NULL estado`

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans revisa la respuesta editada, y el código al final.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con los datos reales de la tabla, lo que obtengo y lo que espero.No agarra el order by por el nombre..está ordenando por el id

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans ¿probaste la consulta como está al final de la respuesta?

Comment: Esta consulta con union me trae los mismos datos originales de la tabla en su mismo orden

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans ¿en el primer grupo qué registros deben quedar primero, los que tienen estado `NULL` o los que tienen estado `1`?

Comment: en el primer grupo los estado 1 y NULL ordenados por nombre ASC y en el 2do grupo los estados 0 ordenados por nombre ASC.En la pregunta estan los detalles de lo que obtengo y lo que espero como resultado final y los datos y valores de la tabla.

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans en ese caso tendrás que poner en cada sub-consulta un valor que sirva para ordenar los grupos en los resultados finales. Revisa ahora la segunda parte, he puesto una columna `m_order` que servirá luego para ordenar por fuera por cada sub-grupo.

Comment: Gracias amigo eso mismo me dijeron en  una respuesta mas arriba y funciono.Muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto, lo vi al terminar de editar la respuesta. Me alegro de que se haya resuelto. Saludos.